# How to add one integer to a feature in a rails data set using the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a database full of some information, but I need to go into the rails console and add one integer to a specific data set in my local database.

I have a column named `times_used`, within that column I need to add one more integer into it.

I've tried,

```
p.update_attribute(:times_used, add: 1)
p.update_attribute(:times_used, add: :1)
p.update_attribute(:times_used, add: [:1])
p.update_attribute(:times_used, + 1)
p.update_attribute(:times_used) + 1
```

I'm wondering, what I am trying to do, is possible? Do I need to loop through these?
Much thanks to anybody for taking a quick look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
MyModel.where(id: 1).update_all('times_used = times_used + 1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I like how your approach allows you to make changes to everything, and also individual elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `increment!` method, take a look: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!

```
//would be something like
p.increment!(:times_used)
```